# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/NamingStrategy$SuffixingRandom$BaseNameResolver

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

i have a problem about Bean creation in xml definer.

When i run the application on server it shows me the first page but when i go to /customer/list it gives me http error - 500

In the tutorial he does nothing else of what i've done.

I can't show you all the .JAR files in the LIB but i have all the dependency he has in the tutorial example.

I am not using Maven, its a normal Dynamic Web Project so i can't just pass to Maven Project.

I've tried to change the Bean name trying to understand if it was a problem of existing object.

This is my Servlet:

```java
package com.luv2code.testdb;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class TestDbServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/TestDbServlet")
public class TestDbServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // setup connection variables
        String user = "springstudent";

        String pass = "springstudent";

        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true";

        String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";

        // get connection  to database

        try {

            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            out.println("Connecting to database: " + jdbcUrl);

            Class.forName(driver);

            Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, user, pass);

            out.println("SUCCESS!!");

            myConn.close();


        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            throw new ServletException(exc);
        }
    }
```

This is my CustomerController:

```java
package com.luv2code.springdemo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String listCustomer(Model theModel) {

        return "list-customer";

    }

}
```

This is my definer.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo" />

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true" />
        <property name="user" value="springstudent" />
        <property name="password" value="springstudent" /> 

        <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>  

    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.luv2code.springdemo.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
        </property>
   </bean>    

    <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />

    <!-- Add support for reading web resources: css, images, js, etc ... -->
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>


</beans>
```

and this is my web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>spring-mvc-crud-demo</display-name>

  <absolute-ordering />

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml</param-value> 
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The exception encountered is:

*org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/NamingStrategy$SuffixingRandom$BaseNameResolver *

- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.cfg.Environment *

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add this jar to your project [net.bytebuddy](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.8.0).
But I recommend to use maven for these purposes.